# gdal_calc amin fails when passing more than 23 input files

Tags: python, r, numpy, raster, gdal

I've written an R function that calls `gdal_calc.py` to calculate the pixel-wise minimum value across a `RasterStack` (series of input raster files). I've done this because it's much faster than `raster::min` for large rasters. The function works well for up to 23 files, but throws a warning when passing 24 or more, returning an output raster filled with zeroes.

Since R is just preparing a system call to `python gdal_calc.py`, this question is not specific to R and I encourage python/numpy aficionados to read on.

Here's the function. The structure of the eventual `gdal_calc` call is shown in the warning message thrown by the problematic usage at the bottom of this post.

```
gdal_min <- function(infile, outfile, return_raster=FALSE, overwrite=FALSE) {
  require(rgdal)
  if(return_raster) require(raster)
  # infile:        The multiband raster file (or a vector of paths to multiple 
  #                 raster files) for which to calculate cell minima.
  # outfile:       Path to raster output file.
  # return_raster: (logical) Should the output raster be read back into R?
  # overwrite:     (logical) Should outfile be overwritten if it exists?
  gdal_calc <- Sys.which('gdal_calc.py')
  if(gdal_calc=='') stop('gdal_calc.py not found on system.')
  if(file.exists(outfile) & !overwrite) 
    stop("'outfile' already exists. Use overwrite=TRUE to overwrite.", 
         call.=FALSE)
  nbands <- sapply(infile, function(x) nrow(attr(GDALinfo(x), 'df')))
  if(length(infile) > 26 || nbands > 26) stop('Maximum number of inputs is 26.')
  if(length(nbands) > 1 & any(nbands > 1)) 
    warning('One or more rasters have multiple bands. First band used.')

  if(length(infile)==1) {
    inputs <- paste0('-', LETTERS[seq_len(nbands)], ' ', infile, ' --', 
                     LETTERS[seq_len(nbands)], '_band ', seq_len(nbands), collapse=' ')
    n <- nbands
  } else {
    inputs <- paste0('-', LETTERS[seq_along(nbands)], ' ', infile, ' --', 
                     LETTERS[seq_along(nbands)], '_band 1', collapse=' ')
    n <- length(infile)
  }

  message('Calculating minimum and writing to ', basename(outfile))
  system2('python',
          args=c(gdal_calc, inputs,
                 sprintf("--outfile=%s", outfile),
                 sprintf('--calc="amin([%s], axis=0)"', 
                         paste0(LETTERS[seq_len(n)], collapse=',')),
                 '--co="COMPRESS=LZW"',
                 if(overwrite) '--overwrite'),
          stdout=FALSE
  )
  if(return_raster) raster(outfile) else invisible(NULL)
}
```

And here is a dummy raster grid, written to `'test.tif'` in the present working directory. For simplicity, and to demonstrate that the problem is not due to a peculiar individual raster, I pass the same input file several times to gdal_calc, rather than passing a number of different files.

```
library(raster)
writeRaster(raster(matrix(runif(100), 10)), 'test.tif')
```

The function works fine for 23 input files:

```
r <- gdal_min(rep('test.tif', 23), f_out <- tempfile(fileext='.tif'),
              return_raster=TRUE)
plot(r)
```

... but not for ≥ 24:

```
r <- gdal_min(rep('test.tif', 24), f_out <- tempfile(fileext='.tif'),
              return_raster=TRUE)
## Calculating minimum and writing to file2310254bcc.tif
## Warning message:
## running command '"python" C:\Python33\Scripts\GDAL_C~1.PY -A test.tif --A_band 1 -B test.tif --B_band 1 -C test.tif --C_band 1 -D test.tif --D_band 1 -E test.tif --E_band 1 -F test.tif --F_band 1 -G test.tif --G_band 1 -H test.tif --H_band 1 -I test.tif --I_band 1 -J test.tif --J_band 1 -K test.tif --K_band 1 -L test.tif --L_band 1 -M test.tif --M_band 1 -N test.tif --N_band 1 -O test.tif --O_band 1 -P test.tif --P_band 1 -Q test.tif --Q_band 1 -R test.tif --R_band 1 -S test.tif --S_band 1 -T test.tif --T_band 1 -U test.tif --U_band 1 -V test.tif --V_band 1 -W test.tif --W_band 1 -X test.tif --X_band 1 --outfile=C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpK4heMM\file2310254bcc.tif --calc="amin([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X], axis=0)" --co="COMPRESS=LZW"' had status 1
```

---

The traceback given when executing the latter directly from the terminal is:

```
"python" C:\Python33\Scripts\GDAL_C~1.PY -A test.tif --A_band 1 -B test.tif --B_band 1 -C test.tif --C_band 1 -D test.tif --D_band 1 -E test.tif --E_band 1 -F test.tif --F_band 1 -G test.tif --G_band 1 -H test.tif --H_band 1 -I test.tif --I_band 1 -J test.tif --J_band 1 -K test.tif --K_band 1 -L test.tif --L_band 1 -M test.tif --M_band 1 -N test.tif --N_band 1 -O test.tif --O_band 1 -P test.tif --P_band 1 -Q test.tif --Q_band 1 -R test.tif --R_band 1 -S test.tif --S_band 1 -T test.tif --T_band 1 -U test.tif --U_band 1 -V test.tif --V_band 1 -W test.tif --W_band 1 -X test.tif --X_band 1 --outfile=C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpK4heMM\file2310254bcc.tif --calc="amin([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X], axis=0)" --co="COMPRESS=LZW"

0.. evaluation of calculation amin([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X], axis=0) failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2208, in amin
    amin = a.min
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'min'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\GDAL_C~1.PY", line 329, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\GDAL_C~1.PY", line 326, in main
    doit(opts, args)
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\GDAL_C~1.PY", line 275, in doit
    myResult = eval(opts.calc)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2211, in amin
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 29, in _amin
    return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Again, this runs as I had expected when removing the reference to `X`.

I am using `Python 3.3.5`, `gdal 1.11.1`, and `numpy 1.9.1` on Win 10 x64.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: I don't know anything at all about `gdal`, but browsing the code for `gdal_calc.py` I do see `for X in range(0,nXBlocks):` at one point, which might either clobber or get clobbered by the `X` value in the input.

Comment: Ah, the issue may be fixed actually in the latest (unreleased?) version of GDAL. See [https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/121](this change) which I suspect will prevent any namespace clashes between the two `X` values.

Comment: Thanks for digging into the source, @Blckknght. I'll see if I can install the dev version and report back.

Comment: @Blckknght - Replacing my gdal_calc.py with the one [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/c8d725c6f8ef70f217941074e2d2ca737a70a6e9/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py) did the trick. Post as an answer if you like... if no one beats you to it I'll award you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you were running into was that the `X` variable from the `calc` input was colliding with the variable created by a loop in the `doit` function:

```
for X in range(0,nXBlocks):
```

It appears this has already been fixed by the gdal developers (in not yet released code). It now `eval`s the `calc` input in a private namespace (a dictionary), rather than in the function's local namespace, so the `X` variable from the loop doesn't conflict with the `X` value from the input any more.